# how do i call a function in loop from another function in void loop arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

```
#define CLK 2
#define DT 3
#define SW 4

#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_PCF8574.h>
LiquidCrystal_PCF8574 lcd(0x27);

int counter = 0;
int currentStateCLK;
int lastStateCLK;
int lastCLK,cnt=0,btnState,lastPress=0;
String currentDir ="";
unsigned long lastButtonPress = 0;

char *mainmenu[] ={"SET MODE","SET TEMP","SET HUMD","SERVO","RESET"};
char *setmode[] ={"INCUBATOR","HATCHER","BACK"};
void setup() {
  
  // Set encoder pins as inputs
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x27);
  pinMode(CLK,INPUT);
  pinMode(DT,INPUT);
  pinMode(SW, INPUT_PULLUP);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setBacklight(255);
  lcd.home(); lcd.clear();

  Serial.begin(9600);
  lastStateCLK = digitalRead(CLK);
  delay(100);
  if(EEPROM_READ(0)==NULL){
    SET_MODE();
  }
  Serial.print(EEPROM_READ(0));
}
void loop(){
  disp();
  rot();
}
void disp(){
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("      KGF");
}
void rot() {
  int lim=sizeof(mainmenu)/2;
  Serial.print(lim);
  currentStateCLK = digitalRead(CLK);
  if (currentStateCLK != lastStateCLK  && currentStateCLK == 1){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    if (digitalRead(DT) != currentStateCLK) {
      counter --;
      if(counter<0){
        counter=lim-1;
      }
    } 
    else {
      // Encoder is rotating CW so increment
      counter ++;
      if(counter>lim-1){
        counter=0; 
    }
    lcd.print(mainmenu[counter]);
    
  }
  lastStateCLK = currentStateCLK;

  int btnState = digitalRead(SW);
  if (btnState == LOW) {
    //if 50ms have passed since last LOW pulse, it means that the
    //button has been pressed, released and pressed again
    if (millis() - lastButtonPress > 50) {
      if(counter==0){
          SET_MODE();
        }
      }
    }
    lastButtonPress = millis();
  }
  delay(1);
}
void SET_MODE(){
  int lim=sizeof(setmode)/2;
  int currentCLK = digitalRead(CLK);
  if (currentCLK != lastCLK  && currentCLK == 1){
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
    if (digitalRead(DT) != currentCLK) {
      cnt --;
      if(cnt<0){
        cnt=lim-1;
      }
    } 
    else {
      // Encoder is rotating CW so increment
      cnt ++;
      if(cnt>lim-1){
        cnt=0;
      } 
    }
    lcd.print(setmode[cnt]);
    
  }
  lastCLK = currentCLK;

  btnState = digitalRead(SW);
  if (btnState == LOW) {
    //if 50ms have passed since last LOW pulse, it means that the
    //button has been pressed, released and pressed again
    if (millis() - lastButtonPress > 50) {
      if(setmode[cnt]=="BACK"){
        exit(0);
      }
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      EEPROM_WRITE(0,setmode[cnt]);
      lcd.print("DONE");
    }
    lastPress = millis();
  }
  delay(1);
}
 
void EEPROM_WRITE(int addrOffset, const String &strToWrite)
{
  byte len = strToWrite.length();
  EEPROM.write(addrOffset, len);
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    EEPROM.write(addrOffset + 1 + i, strToWrite[i]);
  }
}
String EEPROM_READ(int addrOffset)
{
  int newStrLen = EEPROM.read(addrOffset);
  char data[newStrLen + 1];
  for (int i = 0; i < newStrLen; i++)
  {
    data[i] = EEPROM.read(addrOffset + 1 + i);
  }
  data[newStrLen] = '\0';
  return String(data);
}
```

I want to call the SET_MODE() function in the loop from rot() function, I am building a menu based program so the SET MODE menu should redirect to the SET_MODE() function, and as I will be adding more menu and sub-menus how can I perform this task.
The SET_MODE() function doesn't work in loop I do not know why, it only works when I all it under void loop() directly.

Comment: It looks like it'd only be called if `btnState == LOW`, 50ms has passed, and `counter == 0`, are you sure that these conditions are being met?

Comment: Do some debugging and examine the values of `btnState`, `counter`, and `lastButtonPress` each call to see if they are what you think they should be.

Comment: yes #mattlangford